# xamarin.forms (android) cannot update app in appstore "android:exported" attribute missing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

as of today something must have changed because we cannot update our app in the appstore.

we are given this error upon upload:

```
Warning: If an activity, service, or broadcast receiver uses intent filters and doesn't have an explicitly-declared value for android:exported, your app can't be installed on a device that runs Android 12 or higher.
```

In the docs is gives this example on how to fix this:

```
<service android:name="com.example.app.backgroundService"
         android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The problem is that this is regarding java and android studio but doesnt translate well into xamarin.forms.

This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.172" package="com.interiorcircle.interiorcircledroid" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="329">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="Interior Circle" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground">
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="asd" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

EDIT:

i have noticed int he obj folder builds that in the manifest, these here do NOT have the attribute in question:

```
<service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PushNotificationActionReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PushNotificationDeletedReceiver" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:name="crc646957603ea1820544.MediaPickerActivity" />
```

has anyone made a similar experience and maybe already solved this issue?

Comment: Is that the manifest in your sources? Look at the manifest in `obj/Debug` or `obj/Release`. There, you will probably see more lines of code - does it say `intent-filter` anywhere? Sounds like Xamarin is a bit behind in what is required; you'll have to copy into your "source" manifest any sections with `intent-filter`, at the correct place(s) in XML hierarchy, and add the missing attribute. That should merge into the final manifest.

Comment: Might be good idea to first delete all `obj` folders in solution, build, and see if that changes `obj` manifest. Maybe something didn't get regenerated properly in some Xamarin or nuget update.

Comment: I looked through the manifest in the obj folders. It seems like all firebase related stuff does not have the exported attribute: see my edit.

Comment: I found a solution. please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I set this on the service attribute...

```
[Service(Exported = true or false)]
```

This resulted in the property being added to the generated manifest file automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is produced, as I found in my question, by the firebase nuget package, that just lacks the android:exported attribute.

HOwever, you can add this by adding this line into your manifest in between application tags:

```
<receiver android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

AS this is such a arbritary namespace, it might not work for ever, so keep in mind that this namespace might change.

I also opend a git issue with this exact problem so that the devs can fix it themselves.

Best

Comment: How do you add this to the project so that you don't need to re-add it whenever the manifest file is regenerated?